# Shoot bullet at a 45 degree angle

Tags: c#, math, xna, angle

I am trying to shoot a bullet at a 45 degree angle. 
However, it keeps shooting straight.

```
float armCos = (float)Math.Cos(0.0f - MathHelper.PiOver2);
float armSin = (float)Math.Sin(0.0f - MathHelper.PiOver2);

bullet.position = new Vector2(
                        arm.position.X + 42 * armCos,
                        arm.position.Y + 42 * armSin);
```

Comment: If `PiOver2` is what it sounds like, it's 90 degrees, not 45. A whole pi is 180 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function that returns vector. Use is on your init bullet function and store into some variable and use it to update your bullet position.

```
public static Vector2 Vector2FromAngle(double angle, bool normalize = true)
{
    Vector2 vector = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angle), (float)Math.Sin(angle));
    if (vector != Vector2.Zero && normalize)
        vector.Normalize();
    return vector;
}
```